# What C++0x feature will have the most impact?

Tags: c++, c++11

What will day to day C++ development be like in a few years?  What C++0x features will change C++ development the most?

In what order should I concentrate learning these new features?

Comment: Perhaps you should add a `crystal-ball` tag?

Comment: @Oded: Let's call this *community wiki*.

Comment: Make the question CW or it'll get closed.

Comment: never mind, found it... community wiki it is...

Comment: @avakar: you are under the wrong impression that making a question CW has any impact on whether it should be closed or not.

Comment: @Andreas Bonini, no I'm not. Subjective and poll-like questions are tolerated and can even become highly ranked when marked CW. And as you can see, the question has indeed been reopened.

Comment: @avakar: and I'm sure it will be closed again fairly soon, and then reopened, and so on. It being CW is completely unrelated to that. (PS: I don't think it should absolutely be closed; I'm just saying that having it as CW shouldn't influence whether it will be "highly ranked" or not)

Comment: This can increase knowledge of new features and their real-life usefulness. Therefore should be CW but is a valid topic.

Comment: @Andreas Bonini, "and I'm sure it will be closed again fairly soon, and then reopened, and so on", apparently not.

Comment: We honestly have a *[the-future]* tag?

Comment: @Dario: On a total of two questions, this one included.

Comment: All answerers: For those of us who are reading this question and its answers and do not have C++0x memorized, please include links to references explaining the features you mention.  Thank you.

Comment: Subjective yes, but argumentative? I dont think so...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's your favorite C++0x feature?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137812/whats-your-favorite-c0x-feature)

Comment: I know this is old now, but here are two relevant MSO posts: [New close reason: “Question asks to predict the future”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20668/new-close-reason-question-asks-to-predict-the-future) and [Are strongly on-topic questions about predicting the future allowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56480/131713).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Lambdas**, because they finally introduce *reasonable* means of harnessing the benefits of functional programming.

Comment: And because they demonstrate the sad result of stuffing fashionable features into 30 years old language.

Comment: Switching C++ from "lasting value" category to "trying, but can't keep up"

Comment: <irony>Stuffing fashionable features into 80 years old languages has given us Haskell and F#</irony>

Comment: Cheap. What 80 years old language is Haskell backwards-compatible with?

Comment: Everyone's here is aware of it, but for the record: the [&]()->return_type horror is fully attributable to keeping compatibility with existing code

Comment: C++0x isn't backwarts compatible either.

Comment: Splitting hairs like this shows you perfectly understand being wrong at the key point.

Comment: Maybe it just shows something about the seriousness of this discussion. Admittedly, the C++0x's lambda syntax is weird  - as is Python's, Lua's, VB.NET's - , but that has not been questioned. We aren't talking about the motivation of their introduction or the principles of programming language evolution (to which most/all (modern) languages are subject), but their usefulness for future C++ programming. And they **are** useful, mainly because they finally provide us with functionality that lay in the nature of C++ (see how functional the STL is built) but couldn't be replicated sufficiently.

Comment: @ima: so you're saying that because of a slightly quirky syntax (which adds expressiveness by allowing you to choose whether to capture by value or reference), we're all doomed, C++ takes a big step backwards and the world is going to end? Can't say I agree. I fail to see how "C++ with lambdas and a non-ideal syntax" can possibly be *worse* than "C++ without lambdas, but which already had a non-ideal syntax for every other feature in the language"

Seriously, complaining about syntax in a discussion of C++? What's the point? C++ wasn't exactly an example of syntactic clarity to begin with

Answer (score 37):

I personaly think that **move semantics** (and rvalue references in general) are the most important change, on par with threads/locks/atomics. Everything else is, more or less, simplification of syntax or standardization of common third-party solutions -- we can write functors when we need lambdas and we have numerous regex libraries. Even for the lack of atomic operations there were some solutions, but there were NO move constructors/move assignment operators.

Being able to move objects changes the whole perception of the language to me. Even though we had RVO and the swap-to-temporary trick to emulate some of it already, it's hard to imagine how the life changes when this is part of everyday life. It's not just `ofstream("log.txt") << "Hi!";`, or the so much faster STL algorithms, it's a whole new way of passing data between functions.

Comment: And a whole new generation of programmers having no clue, what they/others are doing and why it doesn't work.

Comment: +1 - rvalue references allow a whole slew of important constructs and methods that were previously impossible.

Comment: `unique_ptr` is very nice too - move semantics pointer ownership.

Comment: You are right that move semantics is a really good feature, but Boost.Move provides a good even if incomplete emulation of C++ move semantics.

Note the library is just now under review.

Comment: pass-by-value ought to get more popular again. :)

Answer (score 26):

**auto** because people will overuse it.

Comment: *Exactly* what I'm looking for when I need to declare a loop using iterators.. ahh.. no longer having to constantly type `std::vector<std::basic_string<TCHAR> >::const_iterator` every time I want to loop through a vector of strings.

Comment: typedef is somewhat less friendly to the next guy who reads your code, though, and has to keep looking up what your typedefs mean...

Comment: how is `typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring` not friendly to the next guy?

Comment: @Idan K: The problem is more having to typedef every and each STL container you want to iterate over. And writing generic code to handle this type is tedious. The `auto` keyword will remove all that.

Comment: “overuse” … well, I don’t know. I certainly intend to use it *extensively*. Don’t know that that’s “over”using it, though.

Comment: @paercebal: Or, you could just typedef the container a few lines before you use it.

Comment: @paer Absolutely, I prefer `auto x = *it` over `typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type x = *it` anyday.

Comment: @Idan one typedef isn't so bad.  Several hundred typedefs, and it takes the next guy a week of tediously grepping through your header files before he can even begin to understand what is 'really' going on in your code.

Comment: @rlbond : My current code is more than full of `typedef` lines written **only** for loop iterations, and **nothing** else. I contemplated the use of a macro `#define fordef typedef` just for the sake of sick humour. And don't forget the `typename` as correctly commented by FredOverflow. For these reasons (and for metaprograming reasons, but mostly these reasons), I welcome this addition of the `auto` keyword.

Comment: Overuse how, exactly? That'd imply that there was some kind of cost to it, some kind of disadvantage... Which there isn't. It's no less clear than the ridiculous number of layered typedefs we have today.

Comment: I'm really looking forward to using `auto` instead of those lengthy typedef giants, mostly in STL context. Still I'm sure people will use `auto` even in much more trivial places, where the meaning would be much clearer if the full type was typed out. `auto mynum = 4; auto another = mynum*1.f;`

Comment: `auto` also seems like it could make changed to code easier. As in.. want to change from a `map` to a `hash_map`? If your iterators are all auto, it should be a one-line change.

Comment: I already overuse `auto`.  Not just for iterators, but in any iterator-like situation where functions return some unspecified type that you just pass around without really caring about, like `size_t` or `a type convertible to bool`.  Also, once or twice with function pointers.

Comment: You can assign lambda functions to `auto` variables only because their type has no name that you could write down :)

Answer (score 21):

Range-based for-loops.

```
for (int x: numbers) std::cout << x << " ";
```

Yay!

Comment: @Inverse Some range that you can iterator over. For example, an `int[]` or a `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: I assume you can iterate through int[5], but not through int*.
But then I also assume you *can't* iterate through C strings. Will C++ strings at least allow iterating?

Comment: Why would you ever want to use an `int*` in C++? And of course you can iterate through `string`, it defines a range by its `begin()` and `end()` methods.

Comment: At least `BOOST_FOREACH` supports iterating over zero-terminated char arrays. I don't think there is any technical reason why it couldn't be supported natively, if they have chosen to.

Comment: @visitor: Technical reason, no.  But design reason, yes.  `char*` is not a string, it is a pointer.  Maybe it points to the first character in a null-terminated string, but maybe it points to a single char, like its type suggests.

Comment: @luiscubal @Fred @visitor @Dennis: To be clear, iterating over c-strings should be fine. They are arrays (of the type `const char[N]`), and ranged-based for-loops are well-defined for arrays.

Comment: @GMan few people store C-style strings in that type, though. Most people store strings as char*s.

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose True, but this is foreach we're talking about. Would it make sense to use foreach on a pointer to a single char? No. But it *would* make sense to apply it to a char* string.

Comment: @luiscubal: That's not my problem. I'm talking about a string literal which has the type `const char[N]`. If you want to store a pointer to the first character, that's fine, but my comment isn't intended to apply to that anymore. I mean `for (char c : "asd")`, no more no less. And hell, `char* s = "asd"` is deprecated anyway, *at least* use `const char*`.

Comment: @luiscubal: Like I said, its a design decision.  Sure, it makes no sense to pass a pointer to a single character to a range-based for statement.  But that doesn't change the fact that the compiler can't tell the difference between the two, and C++ is a strongly typed language.  Besides, it makes no sense to *have* a pointer to a null terminated character array in the first place.  If you're not dealing with a literal [which GMan is correct in stating the ranged-based for statement will handle appropriately], you should have a container of some sort.

Comment: @GMan Just curious. Since C strings are null-terminated, "abc" is actually const char[4], right? So that means a foreach applied to it would also be applied to the '\0' char, right?

Comment: @luiscubal: Yup. (Which sucks a bit.)

Answer (score 18):

Unicode support. No more cobbles and hacks to get correct handling of unicode characters -- now the entire unicode standard is natively supported by the language.

Answer (score 7):

`auto`, lambdas, and smart pointers.

Comment: vector<auto_ptr>, however, is not.

Comment: I meant auto key word for type variable compile time detection

Comment: @Billy: Right, `std::auto_ptr` is getting deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

Standard facilities for threading and synchronization.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions as a standard library - you know you need them.

Comment: they are in new standard also

Comment: @John boost is not a standard library.

Comment: So what? Moving boost functionality to the standard is not any kind of paradigm shift that will have massive impact, which is what the question was _about_.

Comment: @John: good point, and I agree. Regardless of how awesome regexes are, putting them in the standard library isn't going to have a huge impact *because we already had them in boost*

Answer (score 2):

*this is a great article about new features*
[Explicating the new C++ standard (C++0x), and its implementation in VC10](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/cpp10.aspx#TrailingReturn)

**The auto keyword**    For automatic data-type deduction (at compile time), depending on initialization.

**The decltype keyword**    For deducing data-type from expression, or an auto variable

**The nullptr keyword**     Null pointer is now promoted, and is been awarded a keyword!

**The static_assert keyword**   For compile time assertions. Useful for templates, and validations that cannot be done using #ifdef.

**Lambda Expressions**  Locally defined functions. Inherits features from function-pointers and class objects (functors).

**Trailing Return types**   Mainly useful when templated function's return type cannot be expressed.

**R-value references**  Move semantics - resource utilization before temporary object gets destroyed.

*there are also described new features of Microsoft's new compiler*

Comment: for_each was in C++98 too, but you had to use it with a named function or a function object.

Comment: So it's not `for_each`, but the usage of `for_each` with a lambda, that you're highlighting?

Comment: Just to be a stickler, `auto`'s type is determined by *initialization*, not assignment.

Answer (score 2):

We switched to 2010 about a month ago.  The two most common things we've used are auto and lambda.  Rvalue references have allowed me to do many things that were not possible before, but in day-to-day use they are not AS used as lambda and auto.

Answer (score 0):

**auto** in the for loops, and **lambdas** for the algorithm, I'll start a massive using of for_each.

Answer (score -1):

**Concepts**.  At last, we'll be able to type-check templates before instantiating them, and when we instantiate them incorrectly, we'll get sensible error messages.  Whoops! The C++0X committee couldn't agree and eventually tossed them out.  Ah well, wait for C++1X...