# What is the motivation behind C++11 lambda expressions?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

I am trying to find out if there is an actual *computational benefit* to using lambda expressions in C++, namely *"this code compiles/runs faster/slower because we use lambda expressions"* or is it just a neat development perk open for abuse by poor coders trying to look cool?

*I understand this question may seem subjective, but I would much appreciate the opinion of the community on this matter.*

Comment: I'll take "The Excluded Middle" for $500 Alex.

Comment: So the only two reasons you can think of for a language feature are "it goes faster" or "it's like a go-fast stripe on a rice rocket"?  What's the fancy latin term for "proof by lack of imagination" again?

Comment: This has been enlightening.  Thank you all for the responses.

Comment: faster/slower than what?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I don't think it's nearly as much about the computational performance as increasing the expressive power of the language.

Comment: A programming language without lambda is like a day without sunshine.

Comment: @Brian, you live in Seattle, shouldn't be a big change ;)

Comment: @Brian: then C++ with lambda is kind of like living in the sub-basement but having a television set that shows the sun shining over a rural landscape -- you see the light but it just doesn't feel the same.

Answer (score 43):

The benefit is what's the most important thing in writing computer programs: ***easier to understand code***. I'm not aware of any performance considerations.

C++ allows, to a certain extend, to do *Functional Programming*. Consider this:

```
std::for_each( begin, end, doer );
```

The problem with this is that the function (object) `doer`

1. specifies **what's done** in the loop
2. yet somewhat **hides what's actually done** (you have to look up the function object's `operator()`'s implementation)
3. must be **defined in a different scope** than the `std::for_each` call
4. contains a certain amount of **boilerplate code**
5. is often **throw-away code** that's not used for anything but this one loop construct

Lambdas considerably improve on all these (and maybe some more I forgot).

Answer (score 14):

There's no performance benefit per se, but the need for lambda came as a consequence of the wide adoption of the STL and its design ideas.

Specifically, the STL algorithms make frequent use of functors. Without lambda, these functors need to be previously declared to be used. Lambdas make it possible to have 'anonymous', in-place functors.

This is important because there are many situations in which you need to use a functor only once, and you don't want to give a name to it for two reasons: you don't want to pollute the namespace, and in those specific cases the name you give is either vague or extremely long.

I, for instance, use STL a lot, but without C++0x I use much more for() loops than the for_each() algorithm and its cousins. That's because if I were to use for_each() instead, I'd need to get the code from inside the loop and declare a functor for it. Also all the local variables before the loop wouldn't be accessible, so I'd need to write additional code to pass them as parameters to  the functor constructor, or another thing equivalent. As a consequence, I tend not to use for_each() unless there's strong motivation, otherwise the code would be longer and more difficult to read.

That's bad, because it's well known that using for_each() and similar algorithms gives much more room to the compiler & the library for optimizations, including automatic parallelism. So, indirectly, lambda will favour more efficient code.

Comment: Best "C++ lambda in a nutshell" explanation I've found so far!

Comment: Oh, so... it's that! I was wondering why all lambda code examples are STL based. Given that I avoid the STL as much as possible, I wasn't able to find any benefit from lambdas, because I've never faced the STL readability problem (which is perhaps one of the reasons why I avoided the STL from day one).

Answer (score 9):

IMO, the most important thing about lambda's is it keeps related code close together.  If you have this code:

```
std::for_each(begin, end, unknown_function);
```

You need to navigate over to `unknown_function` to understand what the code does.  But with a lambda, the logic can be kept together.

Comment: Ideally, "unknown_function" would be named well enough to give you a good idea of what it does.

Comment: @Fred: If you have the lambda definition right there at the point of use, the reader is spared the effort of wondering if the function is well-named or not, and the writer is spared the effort of having to pick a good name for a trivial operation that's only going to be used in one place.

Comment: @Jim Lewis: Agreed.  I don't think lambdas are a bad thing.  But at the same time I don't think it's always a bad thing to move a loop body into a functor.  As always, use what's best for your situation.

Comment: "move a loop body into a functor" - not always, of course. But if the code isn't used elsewhere (and you want to indicate that this is the case), the boilerplate of an `operator()` in a class in an anonymous namespace in C++03 is kind of boring ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Lambdas are syntactic sugar for functor classes, so no, there is no computational benefit. As far as the motivation, probably any of the other dozen or so popular languages which have lambdas in them?

One could argue it aids in the readability of code (having your functor declared inline where it is used).

Answer (score 5):

Although I think other parts of C++0x are [more important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844607/what-c0x-feature-will-have-the-most-impact), lambdas are more than just "syntactic sugar" for C++98 style function objects, because they can capture contexts, and they do so *by name* and then they can take those contexts elsewhere and execute. This is something new, not something that "compiles faster/slower".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
void something_else(std::function<void()> f)
{
        f(); // A closure! I wonder if we can write in CPS now...
}
int main()
{
        std::vector<int> v(10,0);
        std::function<void ()> f = [&](){ std::cout << v.size() << std::endl; };

        something_else(f);
}
```

Comment: No, it's not new. Lambdas capture by name at the point of definition. Exactly like function-objects with a constructor. Because lambda *are* syntactic sugar for function-object and could have been implemented as a source-to-source rewrite (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/10/28/lambdas-auto-and-static-assert-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-1.aspx for examples of such rewrite). Well, it's not possible anymore in recent draft due to other reason : Stateless lambda must now decay to function pointer, so it's a bit different now than plain function-object, but not for the capture part.

Comment: @Thomas Petit: Function object with a constructor has no concept of scope at the point of definition. To automatically rewrite a [&] lambda as a functor one would have to examine its full source and examine the full source of the program before the lambda's definition to resolve the types associated with the names used in the lambda. Not a syntax transformation.

Comment: Not a syntax transformation, but a cleaner syntax for something that could be done previously. Hence syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 2):

Well, compare this:

```
int main () {
    std::vector<int> x = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19};

    int center = 10;
    std::sort(x.begin(), x.end(), [=](int x, int y) {
        return abs(x - center) < abs(y - center);
    });

    std::for_each(x.begin(), x.end(), [](int v) {
        printf("%d\n", v);
    });

    return 0;
}
```

with this:

```
// why enforce this to be defined nonlocally?
void printer(int v) {
    printf("%d\n", v);
} 

int main () {
    std::vector<int> x = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19};

    // why enforce we to define a whole struct just need to maintain a state?
    struct {
        int center; 
        bool operator()(int x, int y) const {
            return abs(x - center) < abs(y - center);
        }
    } comp = {10};

    std::sort(x.begin(), x.end(), comp);

    std::for_each(x.begin(), x.end(), printer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the second is even legal. AFAIK function-local types must not be used as template arguments. Or did C++2003 fix this embarrassing problem?

Comment: @sbi: Templates? What templates? Anyway, the 2nd piece is still compiled in c++0x mode (note the use of initializer list), as the OP just ask for the motivation of lambda expressions.

Comment: `std::sort()` and `std::for_each()` are the templates @sbi referred to. C++0x lifts that restriction though.

Answer (score 2):

"*a neat development perk open for abuse by poor coders trying to look cool?*"...whatever you call it, it makes code a **lot** more readable and maintainable. It does not increase the performance.

Most often, a programmer iterates over a range of elements (searching for an element, accumulating elements, sorting elements etc). Using functional style, you immediatly see what the programmer intends to do, as different from using for loops, where everything "looks" the same.

Compare algorithms + lambda:

```
iterator longest_tree = std::max_element(forest.begin(), forest.end(), [height]{arg0.height>arg1.height});
iterator first_leaf_tree = std::find_if(forest.begin(), forest.end(), []{is_leaf(arg0)});
std::transform(forest.begin(), forest.end(), firewood.begin(), []{arg0.trans(...));
std::for_each(forest.begin(), forest.end(), {arg0.make_plywood()});
```

with oldschool for-loops;

```
Forest::iterator longest_tree = it.begin();
for (Forest::const_iterator it = forest.begin(); it != forest.end(); ++it{
   if (*it.height() > *longest_tree.height()) {
     longest_tree = it;
   }
}

Forest::iterator leaf_tree = it.begin();
for (Forest::const_iterator it = forest.begin(); it != forest.end(); ++it{
   if (it->type() == LEAF_TREE) {
     leaf_tree  = it;
     break;
   }
}

for (Forest::const_iterator it = forest.begin(), jt = firewood.begin(); 
     it != forest.end(); 
     it++, jt++) {
          *jt = boost::transformtowood(*it);
    }

for (Forest::const_iterator it = forest.begin(); it != forest.end(); ++it{
    std::makeplywood(*it);
}
```

(I know this pieace of code contains syntactic errors.)